# How to find duplicates on two columns with distinct values in 3rd column

Tags: oracle

I have 3 columns a,b,c in table.i need to find the duplicates for the columns a & b but with distinct value in c column.

Comment: Can you please post an example of your data, your desired result and what you already tried to achieve the right result?

Comment: column a values: 1,2,3---column b values: a,b,c
column c values:-100,200,300
I want those records like :-

Comment: select C.shpnum, c.shpgidk, c.deargn from CCDBREPDATA.CDCALH C
join(select shpnum ,shpgid,count(*)as count from CCDBREPDATA.CDCALH 
where deargn !=' ' 
group by shpnum,shpgid
having count(*) >1 
)j on c.shpnum=j.shpnum and c.shpgid=j.shpgid 
 group by c.shpnum,c.shpgid,c.deargn
 having count(deargn)=1 and deargn !=' ''

Comment: Above is the query I have tried. I want to get all those deargn numbers having duplicate shpnum and shpgid.  i don't want the query to return those records which has duplicated deragn column as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
with test(a, b, c) as (
select 1, 2, 10 from dual union all
select 1, 2, 20 from dual union all
select 4, 5, 30 from dual union all
select 4, 5, 30 from dual union all
select 3, 2, 3 from dual union all
select 6, 2, 2 from dual
)
select a, b
from test
group by a,b
having count(distinct c) > 1
```

That is, you need to aggregate for `A,B`, but only keeping pairs for which there are more `DISTINCT` values for column `C`